# Twilio answer button

Tags: twilio

Instead of having browser calls answered immediately, how do I create an answer or decline message? Then have the decline stop the incoming call or send to voicemail if that were setup. I would also like to setup a mute/unmute button and keypad for entering numbers as need if call is placed to an automated system, Don't see any examples in docs or quick start.

```
Twilio.Device.incoming(function (conn) {
conn.accept();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also prompt the user about the call and give the option to accept or reject the call, by making use of the connection.reject()  function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 Twilio.Device.incoming(function (connection) {
    if (confirm('Accept incoming call from ' + connection.parameters.From + '?')){
        connection.accept();
    } else {
        connection.reject();
});
```

See also the mute and sendDigits functions of connection:
https://www.twilio.com/docs/client/connection

Comment: Thank you that worked. I have gotten the mute working but cannot get it to unmute after I  mute the call. Both unmute() which is deprecated and mute(false); do not unmute the call.